# Error starting up dns forward zone file

Tags: 12.04, server, dns, syslog

I am working setting up my DNS, but i am getting errors in: tail -f /var/sys/log.
I have setted up a static ip-adress in networks: 192.168.10.1

```
May 11 18:13:54 s180368 named[3582]: command channel listening on ::1#953
May 11 18:13:54 s180368 named[3582]: managed-keys-zone: loaded serial 2
May 11 18:13:54 s180368 named[3582]: zone 0.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
May 11 18:13:54 s180368 named[3582]: zone 127.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
May 11 18:13:54 s180368 named[3582]: zone s180368.com/IN: has no NS records
May 11 18:13:54 s180368 named[3582]: zone s180368.com/IN: not loaded due to errors.
May 11 18:13:54 s180368 named[3582]: zone localhost/IN: loaded serial 2
May 11 18:13:54 s180368 named[3582]: zone 255.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
May 11 18:13:54 s180368 named[3582]: all zones loaded
May 11 18:13:54 s180368 named[3582]: running
```

This is my forward zone file (db.s180368.com):

```
;
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     ns.s180368.com. root.s180368.com. (
                              2         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
ns      IN      NS      192.168.10.1
@       IN      A       127.0.0.1
```

Named.conf.local:

```
#FORWARD LOOKUP ZONE

zone "s180368.com" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/db.s180368.com";
};
```

/etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       server

192.168.10.1    s180368.com     s180368

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

/etc/resolv.conf

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
search s180368.com
```

Answer (score 1):

These two lines are the problem:

```
s180368.        IN      NS      192.168.10.1
s180368.        IN      A       127.0.0.1
```

The dot on the end of the name makes it into a fully qualified domain name rather than just a hostname under the zone.  In essence bind thinks you're trying to include information about a full domain name called `s180368` (without `.com`) which is not inside the zone `s180368.com`.

You probably wanted something more like:

```
ns              IN      NS      192.168.10.1
@               IN      A       127.0.0.1
```

`@` is a shortcut for the full zone name in this case `s180368.com.`  You're already using it for the SOA record above it.

Note: the registrar may require two different nameserver addresses in which case you should have an ns1 and ns2 and have these names and IP addresses (for glue) match the ones you give the registrar.  Your registrar may also attempt to verify that your nameservers are set up correctly especially when using glue records, and if so, will fail because the nameservers are local IPs that are only relevant on your local network (only resolvers within your local network would successfully resolve the hostname).

Comment: Thanks! See edit. When I try to do: nslookup s180368. It cant still find the domain. I am really unsure what is going wrong.

Comment: Presumably you mean `nslookup s180360.com` with the .com?  This domain is showing up as not registered for me.  You realise that to use a domain ending in .com it needs registration with a registrar as "com." resolves down to Verisign?  It's then the .com servers that will refer resolvers down to your domain's nameservers.  I'm confused as to what you're trying to do, why you need a .com domain and why it's not registered, or is this just a sample (not actual) domain for way of providing an example?  Do you really need to host a nameserver at all?  And if so did you want your own local TLD?

Comment: I am just trying to this local on my computer.

Comment: Then you don't need a name server, just an entry in your hosts file. Google hosts file.